# How to Preserve Case Sensitivity for Custom Headers in MinIO .NET SDK's Presigned URLs?

Tags: c#, .net, minio

I'm using MinIO in conjunction with the .NET SDK to generate presigned URLs for object downloads. I have a specific requirement to include a custom header in the presigned URL with case sensitivity preserved. However, when I attempt to add headers to the PresignedGetObjectArgs, it appears that the headers are transformed to lowercase in the resulting URL.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```cs
var args = new PresignedGetObjectArgs()
    .WithBucket(model.BucketName)
    .WithExpiry(model.ExpireIn)
    .WithHeaders(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "versionId", model.VersionId } });

return _minioClient.PresignedGetObjectAsync(args);
```

The problem is that the resulting URL ends up with lowercase headers, like this:
[http://127.0.0.1:9000/testbucket/1.png?[..someheaders]&versionid=somevalue](http://127.0.0.1:9000/testbucket/1.png?%5B..someheaders%5D&versionid=somevalue)

What I want is for the custom header "versionId" to retain its original case sensitivity in the presigned URL, like this:
[http://127.0.0.1:9000/testbucket/1.png?[..someheaders]&versionId=somevalue](http://127.0.0.1:9000/testbucket/1.png?%5B..someheaders%5D&versionId=somevalue)

Is there a way to achieve this case-sensitive preservation for custom headers in MinIO's .NET SDK when generating presigned URLs?